# Diable body of jQuery tabs, use only the tabs for navigation

Tags: jquery-ui

I want the styles and interaction of jQuery tabs standalone. I want to use the tabs for my primary navigation but don't want to wrap the entire page in a div.tabs, or use the #anchor setup imposed by jQuery tabs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you still go ahead with the imposed markup and just hide the tabs?

To hide the tabs, you can do this:

```
$("#my_tabs_container") // your original element that you converted to tabs
    .tabs("widget") // get the widget container
    .find(".ui-tabs-nav") // locate the tab container
    .hide(); // get rid of it
```